# libuv event loop: prepare handle and check handle usage

Tags: c++, c, node.js, libuv

What is the reason to invoke the `prepare handle callback` and the `check handle callback` in the libuv event loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The i/o operations happen between those 2, so you may want to perform some operation before blocking for i/o (prepare handles), and after i/o (check handles).

This diagram illustrates how the libuv event loop operates internally: http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/design.html#the-i-o-loop

Comment: Can you give example for one such task?